# Given a string of html code, how can I go through every tag and remove ones that is not in my whitelist (in JQuery)?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var whitelist = ['a','div','img', 'span'];
```

Given a block of HTML code, I want to go through **every single tag** using JQuery

Then, if that tag is NOT in my whitelist, **remove it and all its children.**

The final string should now be sanitized.

How do I do that?

By the way, this is my current code to remove specific tags (but I decided I want to do whitelist instead)

```
        var canvas = '<div>'+canvas_html+'</div>';
        var blacklist = ['script','object','param','embed','applet','app','iframe',
        'form','input', 'link','meta','title','input','button','textarea'
        'head','body','kbd'];
        blacklist.forEach(function(r){
            $(canvas).find(r).remove();
        });
        canvas_html = $(canvas).get('div').html();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
var whitelist = ['a','div','img', 'span'];
var output = $('<div>'+canvas_html+'</div>').find('*').each(function() {
  if($.inArray(this.nodeName.toLowerCase(), whitelist)==-1) {
    $(this).remove();
  }
}).html();
// output contains the HTML with everything except those in the whitelist stripped off
```

Comment: Replacing your `whitelist` array with `{a: true, div: true, ... }` and your `$.inArray` with a simple `!whitelist[this.nodeName.toLowerCase()]` might be worthwhile.

Comment: @muistooshort +1 Yes, that will make it more efficient by totally eliminating array traversal - especially if the whitelist is big.

Comment: @techfoobar this doesn't work. (if you remove the conditional inside), output will be blank.

Answer (score 4):

try:

```
$(canvas).find(':not(' + whitelist.join(', ') + ')').remove().html();
```

The idea is to turn array of whitelist into `"el1, el2, el3"` format, then use `:not` selector to get the elements that's not in the whitelist, then delete.

This obviously could be expensive depending on the size of your html and whitelist.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, using jQuery to sanitize HTML in order to prevent XSS is not safe, as jQuery is not just parsing the HTML, but actually creating elements out of it. Even though it doesn't insert these into the DOM, in some cases embedded Javascript will be executed. So, for example, the snippet:

```
$('<img src="http://i.imgur.com/cncfg.gif" onload="alert(\'gotcha\');"/>')
```

will trigger an alert.